# Send id through link - Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-chtml

In my view I have a link which is calling a function in Controller. The function in controller is making a pdf. It is supposed to make pdf of only `$model->id`. But I am unable to send the value of $model->id into controller via my link.

**View**

```
<?php
        echo CHtml::link('Save/Print',array('print'),array('class'=>'btnPrint btn btn-info','target'=>'new'));
    ?>

<?php
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
        'data'=>$model,
        'attributes'=>array(
            'id',
            'name',
            'father_name',
            'cnic',
            'customername',
        ),
    )); 
?>
```

**Controller**

```
  public function actionPrint($id) {
    ini_set('max_execution_time',360);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');

    $mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf('','A4');

    $mPDF1->SetHTMLHeader('<h3 style="text-align: center;">'.mb_strtoupper(str_replace('Hello','',Yii::app()->name),'UTF-8').'</h3>');

    // $id=35;
    $records = Candidate::model()->findByPk($id);
    $html = '';
    $html .= $this->renderPartial('view', array('model'=>$records),true);
    $mPDF1->WriteHTML($html, false);
    $mPDF1->Output();
}
```

How will I send the value of id?

Comment: do you want to show this link in cgridview?

Comment: @kumar_v  no i just want a button which will make a pdf of CGridView

Comment: You want to take the pdf output with cgridview content. right?

Comment: You can use any of these extension: http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/?tag=PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go like this for singel link

```
// $model->id is the id you want to send
echo CHtml::link(
    'Save/Print',
     Yii::app()->createUrl('Save/Print' , array('id' => $model->id)),
     array('class'=>'btnPrint btn btn-info','target'=>'_blank'));
```

if you want it in a grid

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
        'data'=>$model,
        'attributes'=>array(
            array(
                'name' => 'id',
                'value' => 'echo CHtml::link(
                    "Save/Print",
                    Yii::app()->createUrl("Save/Print" , array("id" => $data->id)),
                    array("class"=>"btnPrint btn btn-info","target"=>"_blank"));',
                'type' => 'raw',
            ),
            'name',
            'father_name',
            'cnic',
            'customername',
        ),
    ));
```

Comment: I am trying to send it single way but value is not going..its not working.

Comment: what is then name of controller and action?

Comment: what is the generated url like?